# $\mathcal{Z}(y-x)$ is a normal affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is something basic question and be may be silly, still it boggles my mind thats why I am asking. 
Consider the normal affine variety $X=\mathcal{Z}(y-x)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. I am going to prove that $X$ is normal at $(0,0)$ by showing local ring at $(0,0)$ is normal domain using definition i.e. every element in $K(X)$ (which is $Frac(\mathcal{O}(X))$ = $Frac(\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)})$) which is integral over $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$ is in $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$. Now $\frac{y}{x}$ is an element of $K(X)$ and $\frac{y}{x} = 1$ in $K(X)$; hence $\frac{y}{x}$ is a root of $t-1 \in \mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}[t]$ and hence integral over $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$ but $\frac{y}{x}$ is not regular at $(0,0)$. On the other hand from the expression $\frac{y}{x}=1$ in $K(X)$; both $\frac{y}{x}$ and $1$ are elements of $K(X)$ and $1 \in \mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$ so $\frac{y}{x} \in \mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$ which should not be possible. Definitely I am telling something wrong but I can't find where I am wrong. This is I am doing similar to $(0,0)$ is not normal point of $\mathcal{Z}(y^2-x^3)$ since $\frac{y}{x}$ is a root of $t^2 -x \in \mathcal{O}_{(0,0), \mathcal{Z}(y^2-x^3)}[t]$. Please clarify my mistake.

Comment: $\bar{y}/\bar{x}=1$ in the  local ring $\mathcal{O}_{(0, 0)}$ since (if you recall the definition of a localization) $1\cdot(\bar{y}-\bar{x})=0$ in $k[X]$. $\bar{x}$ denotes the image of $x$ in the co-ordinate ring of $X$.

Comment: Yahh; but $\frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}$ should not be the element of $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$.

Comment: Well. Probably the source of your confusion is the notation. In the co-ordinate ring $k[X]$, $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the same elements. So the fraction is 1 in the localization $k(X)$ the function field of $X$. Now the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{(0, 0)}\subset k(X)$, so $\bar{y}/\bar{x}=1\in \mathcal{O}_{(0, 0)}.$

Comment: I have $\frac{y}{x}=1$ in $k(X)$; but $1 \in \mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$ hence $\frac{y}{x}=1 \in \mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$ but it should not be. I can't find where I am wrong.

Comment: A rational function on a variety $X$ is regular at a point $P \in X$ if it can be written as $f/g$ with $f,g \in \mathcal{O}(X)$ and $g(P) \neq 0$. So as a function on the line $y = x$, $y/x$ *is* regular at $(0,0)$ precisely because you can write $y/x = 1 = 1/1$.

Answer (score 0):

The co-ordinate ring of $X$ is given by $R=k[x, y]/(y-x)\simeq k[t]$ under the map $x\mapsto t$ and $y\mapsto t$.

Now the local ring of $X$ at the origin is given by $R_{(x, y)}=k[t]_{(t)}$ with function field of $X$, $k(X)\simeq k(t)$.

Now it should be easy to check by hand that  $k[t]_{(t)}$ is integrally closed in $k(t)$.

Comment: Thats fine I did. But  am asking the fallacy or the issue I faced about this kind of particular solution.